# What is the most profitable coin to mine on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: cryptocurrency

Please if you think mining on a RPi is absolutely pointless please note that I don't pay for my electricity and I'm only doing this because I'm interested in crypto stuff and not because I want to get a billionaire or something...

Currently I'm mining Monero on a Raspberry Pi at ~9.5 H/s which would give me 2.44$ per year...

I thought I could get more out of my Pi and looked for other CPU mineable coins and found Coin Magi interesting... So I installed a miner and everything and got 9kH/s which would give me 2-3$ per year (network hashrate very instable)...

I don't want to get rich or something and I'm just doing this because I'm interested in cryptocurrencies and want to see some earnings as well...

So which coin would you prefer to mine on a Raspberry Pi? Monero or Magi? Or do you know other coins which could be mined profitably on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: What units are H/s?

Comment: @Seamus: It's [hashes per second](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Hash_per_second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you might be interested in proof of stake coins? Some of them may take a hefty investment up front. But to match your $2.44 annually you might not have too invest much. They will for sure be easier on the rpi hardware than pow mining